# Is there a tool to simulate web services (REST and SOAP) for testing?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, simulation

I am already familiar with simulation using WSDL and coded XML and/or JSON objects (SOAP UI, as an example). While this could be an option, it is rather heavyweight. It also does not easily work across multiple teams consuming the same service. And there is quite a bit of coding for REST, as REST is still in infant stages.

Use case: A dev team starts with a contract (I give you X and you return object Y) and an acceptance matrix (specific X inputs with the expected Y outputs) and the tool would fire up a simulated service that fulfills the requirements.

The ideal is a tool that can be included in part of a continuous integration cycle. Platform/language not extremely important, as these are service endpoints.

I may be envisioning something that is not currently created (opportunity?), but I would imagine at least one vendor has created something like this. I just have not found it yet.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted the question. I can only undo the vote if you change the question.

Comment: Reworded slightly, although the downvote is no big deal. Thanks for the answer. Will look into.

Comment: I'm looking for exactly the same tool. There is http://www.mbtest.org/ but their SOAP support is not there yet. Online there's https://www.mockable.io/ and https://getsandbox.com/ but like you I need something to integrate into my CI pipeline. Let me know if you solved this.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used the project myself, but you could have a look at json-server ( https://github.com/typicode/json-server ). It allows you to setup a fake rest server using fake data.

Comment: Not a huge deal, but I will see if I can reword slightly. I will look into this. I know SoapUI gives some options and may be an option.